# How to associate Users with Roles in a Data-Tier application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Just reading this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833199.aspx

It states: You cannot add users to roles in a Data-tier Application (DAC) project because DAC projects do not support the EXEC StoredProcedure construct, except within the body of an object, such as a stored procedure or function. For more information, see the following page on the Microsoft Web site: Features Supported in Data-tier Applications.

So, how is it possible to grant any permission to anything as part of the deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging and hacking, I finally have a solution.

#### A few notes first:

- the solution works on a brand-new DAC or an already-deployed DAC you are updating
- my setup is VS10ult run on Win7x64 deploying to SQL Server 2008 R2 hosted in Server 2008 R2
- all my deployment was done from VS10 -- neither SSMS or the [DAC PowerShell Scripts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/managingsql/archive/2010/04/28/dac-powershell-samples.aspx) were able to deploy the DAC (both were attempted locally on the server)
- as well, SSMS was unable to uninstall a DAC from the SQL Server Instance, but the [DAC PS Scripts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/managingsql/archive/2010/04/28/dac-powershell-samples.aspx) were able to (I included my locally-run PS script in the **Footnote** at the bottom)
- the user that deploys/installs the DAC will get their login mapped to the db's dbo user's **Login name**

#### To add a given domain user as a server login and db user with specific permissions:

#### Step 1: create a Login

- open the Data-Tier Application VS10 project
- right-click the folder **Schema Objects** / **Server Level Objects** / **Security** / **Logins**
- click **Add** then **New Item**
- select the template **Database Project** / **Security**
- select **Login (Windows Auth)**
- hit <**TAB**> or click the **Name** textbox
- type the bare login name (eg: for `DOMAIN\USER` just enter `USER`) and hit <**Enter**>
- enter this for your code then save and close the file (**USER.login.sql**)

  ```
  create login [DOMAIN\USER] from windows
  ```

#### Step 2: create a User

- right-click the folder **Schema Objects** / **Database Level Level Objects** / **Security** / **Users**
- click **Add** then **New Item**
- select the template **Database Project** / **Security**
- select **User**
- hit <**TAB**> or click the **Name** textbox
- type the bare user name (eg: for `DOMAIN\USER` just enter `USER`) and hit <**Enter**>
- enter this for your code then save and close the file (**USER.user.sql**)

  ```
  create user [USER]
     for login [DOMAIN\USER]
     with default_schema = dbo;
  ```

#### Step 3: grant the privileges on the user and/or login

- right-click the folder **Scripts** / **Post-Deployment**
- open the file **Script.PostDeployment.sql** for editing
- enter this for your code then save and close the file

  ```
  alter login [DOMAIN\USER] enable
  go

  use [DAC-DB-NAME];

  exec sp_addrolemember db_owner, [USER]
  go
  ```
- note that a set of **grant** statements can be substituted for the **sp_addrolemember**

Ultimately, I think the real difficulty in doing this was how the post-deployment script is run.  When run, the current **Use** database is initially set to **master**, but in order to issue the `exec sp_addrolemember` and/or `grant`s, the `use [DAC-DB-NAME];` must set the current database first.  [End of pure speculation]

Happy Coding!
Robert McCall
"Lasting peace & happiness for ***ALL*** human beings!"

---

Footnote: PowerShell script (using [DAC PS Scripts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/managingsql/archive/2010/04/28/dac-powershell-samples.aspx)) to uninstall & drop a DAC db

```
# *MUST* BE RUN AS Administrator
# Need extra line after next line to select the default 'Yes'
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Import-Module DACModule

$svrName = "SERVER-NAME"
$dacName = "DAC-DB-NAME"

$svrCon = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection $svrName
$svrCon.Connect()

Uninstall-Dac -serverConnection $svrCon -dacInstanceName $dacName -uninstallMode DropDatabase

$svrCon.Disconnect()
```